# How to write a batch for a pkcs ftp upload?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, cryptography, private-key

I'm trying to write a script, which automatically connects to a ftp server and is uploading two simple files. 
I found many guides on the internet for uploading a file via a batch file to a ftp-server and it's working great.

My problem is, that I need to connect to the server with a PKCS certificate.
Is it even possible to write such a script with batch?

If not, are there other possibilities?

System: Windows 7.7601

Current Script:

```
set tempftp=fileserver.ftp
:# create ftp-script
echo OPEN xxx.xx.xx.xx > %tempftp%
echo USER username pwd >> %tempftp%

rem not working:
echo cd FTP

echo send %1 >> %tempftp%
echo disconnect >> %tempftp%
echo quit >> %tempftp%
:# execute
ftp.exe -n -i -s:%tempftp%
del %tempftp%
pause
exit
```

Kind Regards
Mario

*"English is not my first language, please edit for clarity, then remove this comment!"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at [cUrl](http://curl.haxx.se/) since it has many more options including those for authentication.

Comment: thanks for the link, realy nice programm.
May I ask here a question:
i tried the following for a connection:
`start /B curl.exe -x proxy:port --key key.ppk sftp://.../folder1/in/ > result.html`

Currently without uploading, just to see if it works but is tells me:

The following error was encountered:

    Invalid URL 

Some aspect of the requested URL is incorrect. Possible problems:

    Missing or incorrect access protocol (should be http://'' or similar)
    Missing hostname
    Illegal double-escape in the URL-Path
    Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed